# Default value of dynamic type?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, clr

What is the default value of a variable declared as dynamic e.g. `private dynamic banana;`?

Can I rely on the `default()` function when the type is determined at runtime?

The reason I need to find the default value is that I declare a dynamic member of a class that I want to set it once (but not as `readonly`), then use it many times.

How do I check if the dynamic variable has been set to anything other than the default value without knowing what the runtime type is likely to be?

Google came up with nothing on this :S

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check the type with `default(dyanmic.GetType())`

Comment: why dont you use a readonly property of Type dynamic & backing field of type object? That way you can null check the backing field.

Comment: @AkashKava, I am not setting the value in the constructor, so I can't use read only :/

Comment: @gdoron, you're first answer was right: `default(dynamic)`.

Comment: @Sinker, well that depends on what you want to accomplish, I changed the comment because I thought you want something else.

Comment: Read only means private set and public get.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is `null`.

```
dynamic blah;
Console.Write(blah); // crash
Console.Write(blah.GetType()); // NullRef
```

..is that what you meant?

Comment: `Console.Write` does not crash on being passed `null`, it simply prints nothing.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcwe8sfx.aspx

Comment: > @EdS., You get the following error:
>{"The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Console.Write(string)' and 'System.Console.Write(char[])'"}

Comment: @Sinker: That's not a crash

Comment: Hi @EdS., I get an `RuntimeBinderEception` using `Console.Write()` method. In any case, I think it clears up what is happening at runtime with the dynamic type. I forgot to add: I am using .NET 4.0

Comment: @Sinker: Yeah, I was commenting on the assertion that the default value will be null and that it will result in a crash in `Console.Write`.

Comment: @EdS Apologies. Quickly typed on a mobile phone :)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: No problem, of course I have done the same thing :D